# Swift: Handling Fast Swipes in Custom Slide Menu

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `redView: UIView` with a `pan gesture`. It can slide only horizontally. I want this view to stop at certain point when sliding to the left.

Currently, if sliding slowly/normally, it works as it is meant. However, if sliding faster than average / very fast, the view stops with some distance after the needed point.

I am using a `guard` statement inside my `UIPanGestureRecognizer.State` switch like so:

```
case .changed:
    guard abs(redViewX) < 150 else { return }
    //do magic
```

So, if sliding faster, the view may stop at `x = 160` or `171` etc. It depends on how fast you are actually sliding.

Do you know any technic on how to stop the view at the needed point, so that the user can't even swipe to `150 + 1` point?

---

### UPD:

I finally solved the problem. Here is the result: [image]

This is a simplified solution I came up with:

```
func expandMenu(_ value: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            redView.frame.origin.x = value ? -150 : 0
            gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

switch gesture.state {
case .changed:
    let swipingToLeft = translation < 0

    if swipingToLeft {
        guard abs(redViewX) < yellowViewWidth else { return }

        if abs(translation) + abs(redViewX) > yellowViewWidth {
            expandMenu(true)
        } else {
            redView.frame.origin.x += translation
        }
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    } else {
        guard redViewX < 0 else { return }

        if translation - abs(redViewX) > 0 {
            expandMenu(false)
        } else {
            redView.frame.origin.x += translation
        }
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `myView.frame.origin.x` to the value you desire in your `guard`'s `else` block?

Comment: Yes, I have. the problem is that the `guard` statement runs after the `x` position gets `> 150`. So my view goes to `x = 160` and then immediately to `x = 150`. it is noticeable on the screen, so this is not the perfect solution: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-ff274f2bfe2b.gif

Comment: Might I suggest not using a `guard` but setting your view's frame using `min`. For example, `myView.frame.origin.x = min(200, /* however you're calculating origin.x */)`

Answer (score 1):

When the sliding is fast the transition.x value can jump and it looks like in this case you don't handle the update correctly.
For example, origin.x jumps from 250 to 190 and looks like you ignore this update.
I suggest you set the myView.frame.origin.x inside the guard to 200 so it will not be stuck in the middle.
If it will not help - provide more code to make the problem more clear.